# Facebook messenger integration - bot does not provide the responses

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I had integrated the Dialogflow with Facebook messenger
  integration. I had followed the steps in the dialogflow docs.

I am not getting any output /message from the messenger.

I had used `conv.ask()` to respond to the Intents, is that the issue?

Do I need to update the surface capabilities section in actions?

```
'use strict';

  // Import the Dialogflow module and response creation dependencies
  // from the Actions on Google client library.
  const {
    dialogflow,
    BasicCard,

  } = require('actions-on-google');

  // Import the firebase-functions package for deployment.
  const functions = require('firebase-functions');

  // Instantiate the Dialogflow client.
  const app = dialogflow({debug: true});


  function getRandomInt(max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
  }

  const swamiMessages = require('./messages');

  const swamiQuotes =require('./quotes');
  // Intent Mapping 

  //INTENT: 'Default Welcome Intent'.

  app.intent('Default Welcome Intent', (conv) => {
    conv.ask(
        `<speak> <emphasis level="moderate" >   `+
        `Do you want to hear an Inspiring  <break/> Quote or a Message from Swami <break/> Sukhabodhananda ` +
        `Do you want to know about Prasanna Trust <break/>`+
        //`Do you want to know about the upcoming programs` +
      ` </emphasis> </speak>`);
    });

  //INTENT: 'quote'
  //Should get triggered when the user request for an inspiring thought
  // asks for motivation 

  app.intent('quote', (conv) => {
    // when the welcome intent is triggered recite a random quote

    //let quoteNumber= getRandomInt(5);
    //let quote = quotes[quoteNumber].quote; //
      let quote =swamiQuotes.getQuote();

    if (quote) {
        conv.ask(
            `<speak> <emphasis level="moderate" >   `+
            `Let us hear  an Inspiring quote \n` +
            `<break strength="strong"> </break>  `+
            `${quote}` +
            `<break strength="strong"> </break>  `+
            `\nDo you want to hear another quote or message ` +
            ` </emphasis> </speak>`);
        } else
        {
          conv.ask(
            `<speak> <emphasis level="moderate" >   `+
            `Let us hear  an Inspiring quote ` +
            `<break strength="strong"> </break>  `+
            `quotes` +
            `\nDo you want to hear another quote or message ` +
            ` </emphasis> </speak>`);
        }
  });

  // INTENT: message 
  //Should get triggered when the user request for an inspiring message


  app.intent('message', (conv) => {
    // when the welcome intent is triggered recite a random message
    let message =swamiMessages.getMessage();
    //let formattedMessage=swamiMessages.formattedMessage(message);

    conv.ask(
        `<speak> <emphasis level="moderate" >   `+
        `Let us hear  an Inspiring Message ` +
        `<break strength="strong"> </break>  `+
        `${message}`+
        `\nDo you want to hear another quote or message ` +
        ` </emphasis> </speak>`);

    });
```

**Update**

If I make changes to use the dialogflow-fulfillment library, how do I add two default handler functions - one for Actions on Google and one for other integrations?  I'm doing something like

```
intentMap.set(null, googleAssistantOther);
intentMap.set(null, other);
//In place of null should i update the Intent Name and 
// googleAssitantOther and other are callback functions.
```

Comment: Removed tags from title; trademark capitalization; grammar; layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You indicated you're trying to integrate this with Facebook, but you're using the actions-on-google library, which is tailored to respond with messages specifically for the Google Assistant.

If you want to write code that responds for both the Assistant, as well as other platform that Dialogflow supports, you may want to look into the [dialogflow-fulfillment library](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs).

You do not need to do anything with the surface configuration on the Action console.

**Update**

You can use the same Intent definitions - that is an important aspect of developing for multiple platforms. And many things (such as text) work exactly the same between the two. For some things (such as wanting to add some RichResponse objects), you may want to check which platform you're running on with code such as

```
if (agent.requestSource === agent.ACTIONS_ON_GOOGLE) {
  intentMap.set(null, googleAssistantOther);
} else {
  intentMap.set(null, other);
}
```

Comment: How can i use the same Intents which i had developed for the Google Actions - Should i create a seperate Agent?

Comment: Thanks for helping me learn, Can you please let me know how to use SSML in agent.add, i tried creating  a Text Object and used the Test.setSsml and passed the Text to agent.add - but it did not work.  Also can you please help me understand the above text of intentMap.set(null, googleAssistantOther); & intentMap.set(null, other);//In place of null should i update the Intent Name  and googleAssitantOther and other are callback functions. So we would  use 2 seperate functions one for ActionOnGoogle and other is default. Is my understanding correct.

Comment: If you are still having problems with the original question, please update your original question (and make a comment you've updated it) rather than trying to make large elaborations in comments. If you have a new question (and your second part, at least, sounds like it might be a new question), then asking it as a new StackOverflow question is best. If this has answered your original question, then accepting and/or upvoting it is always appreciated.

Comment: @Prisoner, I think you should make a few corrections to your suggested code in order to make it usable for others.
First, you should rename agent to app, according to Ak11's original question. (if it is the same thing ofcourse) You should also define intentMap ( let intentMap = new Map(); ) and define the handler googleAssistantOther, because it's unclear what this handler does

Comment: The `app` and `agent` objects are two completely different things. In fact, they're talking about two completely different libraries. Similarly, `intentMap` isn't defined because it is referenced in the dialogflow-fulfillment library link. Both reference the request for elaboration in the comments.

Comment: (But a reasonable request. The original question should have been updated with what the OP was asking about in the comments. Which would make the answer make more sense.)